# Dart: Copy text to clipboard with one-click

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the email to be copied to the clipboard with one click. Because I want to make a new feature in my app.
**But the variables must exist!**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mcgapp/widgets/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../classes/teacher.dart';

class TeacherDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TeacherDetailsScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.teacher,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Teacher teacher;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: "${teacher.pronoun} ${teacher.name}",
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text("${teacher.firstname} ${teacher.name}" != ""
                ? "${teacher.firstname} ${teacher.name}"
                : "No Name"),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(teacher.subject != ""
                ? teacher.subject
                : "No Subjects"),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.subject),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(teacher.kuerzel != ""
                ? teacher.kuerzel
                : "Nothing"),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.tag),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(teacher.email != ""
                ? teacher.email
                : "No Mail"),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This ListTitel is meant by "email" :

```
 ListTile(
            title: Text(teacher.email != ""
                ? teacher.email
                : "No Mail"),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the **String** to the clipboard like this in an example:

```
void copyToClipboard(String email) {
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: email));
}
```

Moreover, you can notify the user with a **snackbar** or **flushbar** on your UI screen.

```
void copyToClipboard(String email) {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: email)).then((value) { //only if ->
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)); // -> notify the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Clipboard](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html) class from `flutter/services.dart`
and use the `setData` method on click.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a services lib provided by flutter first, import it

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Set the clipboard with your email text or any string value
you can call this method on the list onTap() function

```
await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: /* your data here */));
```

Note: Please use async while calling this Clipboard because it is asynchronous